# What does "app server in my own environment" mean in Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having trouble understanding the specific meaning of "app server implemented in my own environment" as used in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) on how to send upstream messages to the "Cloud" using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/features/notifications/).

**Context**

The documentation is saying that for me to send upstream messages, I need my own app server that implements one of two connection server protocols in HTTP or XMPP.

**The Reason why I am confused**

My expectation is that if I use Firebase, I don't need to create my own server. All of the backend stuff is handled by them. So to me, when they say I need to create my own app server in my own environment, it is contrary to my expectation and understanding and thus makes me second guess the meaning.

**What it is I am specifically confused and asking about**

- What exactly do they mean by app server?
- What exactly do they mean by "in my own environment"?

**Another way my two questions could be asked is:**

- Is an app server in this context meaning just a typical app server that I write on my own using something like Node.JS/Express.JS and host on something like Digital Ocean? and/or
- Is it something I need to do with other Firebase/Google Cloud products (eg Hosting or App Engine)?
- Or could my implementation of the RealTime Database feature on my app be considered an "App Server" as it serves my app with data.

**What I have done so far**

Reading through every single documentation on Firebase relating to Cloud Messaging and browsing around Google.

I have had a solid read of what questions to ask and what to avoid. I am mindful that this question could be something with lots of varying and all correct answers so apologies if that offends one of the rules. But I have come across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288008/are-questions-that-clairify-api-documentation-helpful-and-therefore-a-good-fit-f) on Meta which suggests that asking for clarification on documentation is OK for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is an app server in this context meaning just a typical app server that I write on my own using something like Node.JS/Express.JS and host on something like Digital Ocean?*

Exactly.

> *Is it something I need to do with other Firebase/Google Cloud products (eg Hosting or App Engine)?*

Depends on your use-case. But for Firebase Cloud Messaging, when all you need is to send *Downstream* Messages, you don't need an App Server. You can just make use of the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). If you need to send *Upstream* Messages, then you have to implement your own App Server.

> *Or could my implementation of the RealTime Database feature on my app be considered an "App Server" as it serves my app with data?*

Not exactly. The Firebase Realtime Database *stores* the data you need, but the App Server needed for FCM is something that can *process* requests (Send (*Downstream* and Receive (*Upstream*)).

Comment: PS: The answer seems simple, but I think it did answer the questions. Let me know if something's confusing and I'll try to explain more (if I do know how to). Cheers! EDIT: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

App notifications are sent by Firebase Cloud Messaging server. To send these notifications you will have to tell to which device notifications have to be sent.

So you will have to send the FCM Client ID from your backend server (Node.js, PHP server). You will get the FCM client ID when you integrate Firebase into your app. You will have to store the FCM client ID in your backend server like during registration of a user.

To send a notification to a device retrieve the FCM Client id from your backend server and send it to the Firebase cloud messaging server and it will check if the client id is valid and trigger a notification.